# Can't run python script through SSH

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to use a ssh connection to run a python script on "Bash on Windows". When I do that the ssh just connects and then shuts down again, without executing the python script. I just sends this command over ssh: `python pythontest.py`
I'm using paramiko to establish the ssh connection. The ssh is established with this class:

```
class ssh:
client = None

def __init__(self, address, username, password):
    print("Connecting to server.")
    self.client = client.SSHClient()
    self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(client.AutoAddPolicy())
    self.client.connect(address, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False)

def sendCommand(self, command):
    if(self.client):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)
        while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
            # Print data when available
            if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                prevdata = b"1"
                while prevdata:
                    prevdata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                    alldata += prevdata

                print(str(alldata, "utf8"))
    else:
        print("Connection not opened.")
```

The python script I'm trying to run, works just fine if I call it from the Bash console. The ssh connection works if I ask it do `mkdir test` or something.
Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Is `$python` an environment variable? Where do you define it? Are you sure the right shell profile is invoked for the remote shell?

Comment: No 'python' is not a variable, sorry about the confusion. I don't know about the shell profile. How do I check that?

Comment: `stderr` is also empty? There must be hints in there.

Comment: Try to invoke a dead simple executable first, e.g. `/bin/date`, and see if the paramiko setup is OK. (On profiles: [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), look for the "Invocation" section.)

Comment: I get this if I print 'stderr':<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (EOF received) (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x3f37908 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>

Comment: If I run '/bin/date' it returns the time without any problems

Comment: Have a look at the parallel-ssh library (uses paramiko). The above is a couple lines worth of code with it. https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh